# Subsets of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions, sets

Consider the following demand of products for the next four months.

```
data={1,20,3,40};
```

I could produce the whole demand in the first months, leading to the following "production vector": `{63,0,0,0}`.

As you can imagine, producing everything in the first month leads to high costs of inventory. Another possibility would be {21,0,43,0}.

Now I would like to get all possible combinations of the subsets of `data`, leading to:

```
results=
{{{1},{20,3,40}},
{{1,20},{3,40}},
{{1,20,3},{40}},
{{1},{20,3},{40}},
{{1},{20},{3},{40}},
{1,20,3,4}
}
```

It is important that `Table[Map[Flatten,results][[i]]==data,{i,Length@results}]` is `True` for all `i`. This means that each sublist of `results` has the same order of figures as in data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use:

```
data = {1, 20, 3, 40};

Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length@data];

results = Internal`PartitionRagged[data, #] & /@ %
```

> ```
> {{4}, {3, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
>
> {{{1, 20, 3, 40}},
>  {{1, 20, 3}, {40}},
>  {{1}, {20, 3, 40}},
>  {{1, 20}, {3, 40}},
>  {{1, 20}, {3}, {40}},
>  {{1}, {20, 3}, {40}},
>  {{1}, {20}, {3, 40}},
>  {{1}, {20}, {3}, {40}}}
> ```

---

`IntegerPartitions` is used get the ways in which you can split a list, to be used with the function above.  `Permutations` is used to get all orders of these.  By the way, you could use the function `Compositions` from the Combinatorica package in place of both of these if you want to include zeros.

These specifications are fed to `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` which splits a list into given lengths, e.g. `[{1,2,3,4,5}, {2,1,2}]` -> `{{1,2}, {3}, {4,5}}`.  Users of *Mathematica* versions prior to 8 can use [my `dynamicPartition` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7512/121) in its place.

Comment: You have my +1, but could you go into some detail about the individual steps involved, as I have no idea how you came up with that function. I see how it works, but I think additional exposition would help myself, and the newbies, understand it better.

Comment: Better, but I was trying to understand how `dynP` works. From what I read `Accumulate@p` creates a list of partition points, specifically the end points of the sublists. `{0}~Join~Most@#` shifts the list of points to the right, adding `1` to which creates the start points. Then it is just a matter of supplying those values to `Part`.

Comment: Actually, it would be preferable if the explanation were here as the ToolBag has been closed, and is on SO. That said, when I replied, I did not notice the link. Sorry. :)

Comment: @rcollyer as I recall someone (Oleksandr?) posted a version-8 Internal or Developer function that does what my `dynP` function does.  Do remember what it is?  Perhaps we can use that instead and just leave a link to the Toolbag post for prior version users.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you're probably thinking of ``Internal`PartitionRagged``, which for version 8 is indeed equivalent to your `dynP`. Actually I've never had cause to use it personally, but Andy Ross mentioned it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3433986#3433986).

Comment: @Oleksandr thank you! I should take better notes.

Comment: Alongside ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` we need ``Developer`ParitionMapRagged``. It would be very useful.

Answer (score 6):

You might generate all subsets by placing special markers (asterisks) where a list should be split.

```
data = {1, 20, 3, 40};

(* The asterisks "*" indicate where a list should be split *)
data1 = Insert[data, "*", #] & /@ (Subsets[Range[2, Length[data]]] /.  a_Integer :>  {a})

(* out *)   
{{1, 20, 3, 40}, {1, "*", 20, 3, 40}, {1, 20, "*", 3, 40}, {1, 20, 3, "*", 40}, 
 {1, "*", 20, "*", 3, 40}, {1, "*", 20, 3, "*", 40}, {1,  20, "*", 3, "*", 40}, 
 {1, "*", 20, "*", 3, "*", 40}}

(*  s actually does the splitting  *)
s[list_] := Split[list, # =!= "*" &]

(* t removes asterisks *)
t[list_] := DeleteCases[#, "*"] & /@ list

t[#] & /@ (s[#] & /@ data1)

(* out *)
{{{1, 20, 3, 40}}, {{1}, {20, 3, 40}}, {{1, 20}, {3, 40}}, {{1, 20, 3}, {40}}, 
 {{1}, {20}, {3, 40}}, {{1}, {20, 3}, {40}}, 
 {{1, 20}, {3}, {40}}, {{1}, {20}, {3}, {40}}}
```

---

**Note**

The following snippet targeted all the positions in `data` where splits could be made:

```
Subsets[Range[2, Length[data]]] 
(*  out *)

{{}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}}
```

So the first list had no splits; the second list was split at position 2, that is, after the first element; the third list was split at position 3; ... and the final list was split at positions 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {1, 20, 3, 40};
i = Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[data]];
```

In version 11.2 `TakeList` is introduced which does the same thing as `Internal'PartitionRagged` plus more. But even though `TakeList` has more functionality, it evaluates much faster:

```
Do[Internal`PartitionRagged[data, #] & /@ i, {1000}] // RepeatedTiming
Do[                TakeList[data, #] & /@ i, {1000}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.337, Null}
>   {0.0210, Null}

Answer (score 2):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Map[data[[#]] &, 
 Select[SetPartitions[Range[4]], OrderedQ[Flatten@#] &], {2}]
```

giving

> (*{
>   {{1, 20, 3, 40}},
>
> {{1}, {20, 3, 40}},
>
> {{1, 20}, {3, 40}},
>
> {{1, 20, 3}, {40}},
>
> {{1}, {20}, {3, 40}},
>
> {{1}, {20, 3}, {40}},
>
> {{1, 20},{3}, {40}},
>
> {{1}, {20}, {3}, {40}} 
>   }*)

Answer (score 0):

`TakeDrop` and `FoldPairlist` combination for versions 10+:

Using the first part of Mr.Wizard's answer to generate the partition lengths,

```
lengths = Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length @ data];

FoldPairList[TakeDrop, data, #]& /@ lengths  // Column
```

[image]