# Finding all partitions of a set

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, combinatorics, partitions

I'm looking for straightforward  way to find all the partitions of a set.

`IntegerPartitions` seems to provide a useful start. But then things get a bit complicated.

Imagine we want to find all the ways to partition a list:

```
myList={a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

`IntegerPartitions` gives the some breakdowns, by numbers of elements in each subset.

```
breakdowns=IntegerPartitions[Length[myList]]
```

> {{6},{5,1},{4,2},{4,1,1},{3,3},{3,2,1},{3,1,1,1},{2,2,2},{2,2,1,1},{2,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1}}

The following function, `g`, takes the list and the breakdowns, outputting some useful results (but clearly not all possible results).

```
g[{},_,out_]:=out
g[in_,breaks_,out_]:=g[Drop[in,First@breaks],Rest@breaks,Append[out,Take[in,First@breaks]]]
```

So

```
g[myList,#,{}]&/@IntegerPartitions[Length[myList]]//MatrixForm
```

> [image: matrix output]

---

I suspect that there may be some better alternatives to `g`. Perhaps even a straightforward  list-manipulation command.

---

BTW, we would need to use all permutations of `myList` to ensure we have all the partitions. `Permutations[myList]` would be instrumental for that:

```
Table[g[k,#,{}]&/@IntegerPartitions[Length[myList]],{k,Permutations[myList]}]
```

Comment: Are you not interested in {{a},{b,c,d,e,f}} and similar as well ?

Comment: Does the Combinatorica function `SetPartitions[]` not do what you want?

Comment: Yes, it does! I was not aware of it (or had forgotten about it).  Strange that such a basic command is not an integral part of Mathematica's kernel.  Would you like to exemplify how it works? (I just tried it successfully, but since you made the suggestion...)

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes, for sure. That's why I included the note about `Permutations` at the bottom.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting with `myList = {a, b, c, d, e, f}`, here are a few solutions, in increasing order of generality:

1.

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[myList, #] & /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[myList]]
{{{a, b, c, d, e, f}}, {{a, b, c, d, e}, {f}}, {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}},
 {{a, b, c, d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, {{a, b, c}, {d, e}, {f}},
 {{a, b, c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}},
 {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a, b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}},
 {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}}
```

2.

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[myList, #] & /@ 
        Apply[Join, Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[myList]]]
{{{a, b, c, d, e, f}}, {{a, b, c, d, e}, {f}}, {{a}, {b, c, d, e, f}},
 {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}}, {{a, b}, {c, d, e, f}}, {{a, b, c, d}, {e}, {f}},
 {{a}, {b, c, d, e}, {f}}, {{a}, {b}, {c, d, e, f}}, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}},
 {{a, b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, {{a, b, c}, {d}, {e, f}}, {{a, b}, {c, d, e}, {f}},
 {{a, b}, {c}, {d, e, f}}, {{a}, {b, c, d}, {e, f}}, {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e, f}},
 {{a, b, c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a}, {b, c, d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a}, {b}, {c, d, e}, {f}},
 {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d, e, f}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}},
 {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a, b}, {c}, {d, e}, {f}},
 {{a, b}, {c}, {d}, {e, f}}, {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}},
 {{a}, {b, c}, {d}, {e, f}}, {{a}, {b}, {c, d}, {e, f}},
 {{a, b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a}, {b, c}, {d}, {e}, {f}},
 {{a}, {b}, {c, d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d, e}, {f}},
 {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e, f}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}}
```

3.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
Short[SetPartitions[myList], 5]
{{{a, b, c, d, e, f}}, {{a}, {b, c, d, e, f}}, {{a, b}, {c, d, e, f}},
 {{a, c, d, e, f}, {b}}, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}, {{a, d, e, f}, {b, c}},
 {{a, b, d, e, f}, {c}}, {{a, c}, {b, d, e, f}}, {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}},
 {{a, e, f}, {b, c, d}}, <<184>>, {{a}, {b, d}, {c}, {e}, {f}},
 {{a}, {b, e}, {c}, {d}, {f}}, {{a}, {b, f}, {c}, {d}, {e}},
 {{a, b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}, {{a, c}, {b}, {d}, {e}, {f}},
 {{a, d}, {b}, {c}, {e}, {f}}, {{a, e}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {f}},
 {{a, f}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}}
```

The output of `SetPartitions[]` was rather long, so I had to use `Short[]`. Execute `SetPartitions[myList]` if you want to see everything.

Comment: As a way of checking the output of `SetPartitions[]`, the following should be `True`: `Length[SetPartitions[myList]] == BellB[Length[myList]]`.

Comment: Very nice. Your second solution highlights some additional permutations that I had overlooked.  And of course, the third solution is, as you note, the most general.

Comment: @J.M. +1 thanks for showing the multiple cases

Comment: #2 can now be done quite conveniently without any `Internal` functions, by using `IntegerPartitions` and `TakeList`: https://tio.run/##LY2xCsJAEER7v2JAsFq4LxCuVVJcYScWa7Imi9wGLptCxG@/JMRuePOYyeyDZHZtudb8aXRynPFlwpPQEjqCEF6/w43fsrX3XSIcHzghRFxHNcSIJCXPvi6NNm38Yi69lMTFdYcRjVjvwxr@TyEgFTWvdQE

Answer (score 12):

Based on [`BellList` from Robert M. Dickau](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110063111/http://mathforum.org/advanced/robertd/bell.html):

```
partition[{x_}] := {{{x}}}

partition[{r__, x_}] :=
  Join @@ (ReplaceList[#,
      {{b___, {S__}, a___} :> {b, {S, x}, a},
       {S__} :> {S, {x}}}
      ] & /@ partition[{r}])
```

This is faster than `SetPartitions` on shorter sets:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
myList = {a, b, c, d, e, f};

partition[myList] ~Do~ {500} // Timing // First
SetPartitions[myList] ~Do~ {500} // Timing // First
```

> 0.405
>
> 0.843

Related:

- [Subsets of a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5305/121)

Comment: Note to self: read Mr. Wizard's answer more carefully before attempting the problem! Just spent 10 minutes coming up with essentially the same code. Except I used the `Alternatives` thing you showed me to express the replacement in a single rule: `ReplaceList[#,{b___,{S__},a___}|{b__}:>{b,{S, x},a}]`

Comment: @Simon I love it!  You're schooling me with my own tricks!  This was a copy&paste job from old code but I wish I'd seen that myself.  Honestly it thrills me that you're open to methods like this as I sometimes feel that nobody is listening.  I say again, it's good to have you aboard.  (FWIW it appears that `|` is slightly slower in this application, something I have observed before and you may want to be aware of.  It's probably because of the extraneous "Sequence" operations that are performed.  Still for me the form you show is beautiful.)

Comment: thank you! It's good to be aboard - I've learnt so much in just three months from this community. I'm particularly open to learning new methods with pattern matching, it's such a powerful aspect of the language and I'm only just starting to appreciate how flexible it is.

Comment: Mr. Wizard. This is replacement as its best. Wow! The problem with SetPartitions in Combinatorica is the workhorse function KSetPartitions. Inside there is a lot of copying going on. On the other hand, although your approach is very fast, the implementation in KSetPartitions relies more on the algorithm itself. Yours is fascinating syntax wizardry.

Comment: @Wizard great work with patterns. +1 ! although i need some time to digest this.

Comment: Thank you. With `partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}]`, I for some reason get all the first elements equal to 1? So I see: `{{1, {2, 3, 4}}, {1, {2, 3}, {4}}, {1, {2, 4}, {3}}, {1, {2}, {3, 
   4}}, {1, {2}, {3}, {4}}}`.

Comment: @Alexander It is a two part definition; you *must* evaluate `partition[{x_}] := {{{x}}}` as well as the larger one; without that you'll get the incorrect output you show—with it you'll get `{{{1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 
   2}, {3}, {4}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2}, {4}}, {{1, 
   4}, {2, 3}}, {{1}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}, {{1, 4}, {2}, {3}}, {{1}, {2, 
   4}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}}`

Comment: Ok nice. That works now! I wasn't sure what the double underscore meant.