# Partition a set into $k$ non-empty subsets

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions

The [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets. In Mathematica, this is implemented as `StirlingS2`. How can I enumerate all the sets? Ideally I would like to get a list of lists, where each list contains $k$ lists.

The question [Partition a set into subsets of size k](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/partition-a-set-into-subsets-of-size-k) seems relevant.

Comment: Related: [(8528)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8528/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<< Combinatorica`
KSetPartitions[{a, b, c}, 2]
(*
  {{{a}, {b, c}}, {{a, b}, {c}}, {{a, c}, {b}}}
*)

 StirlingS2[3, 2]
 (* 3 *)
```

Comment: Those who use Cobinatorica on 8 and 9 may be interested in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5574/12).  This is how I usually load it now.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh! Thanks for linking it. All those error msgs are creepy sometimes

Answer (score 10):

This is faster than the Combinatorica function:

```
KSetP[{}, 0] = {{}};
KSetP[s_List, 0] = {};
KSetP[s_List, k_Integer] /; k > Length@s = {};
KSetP[s_List, k_Integer] /; k > 0 :=
 Block[{ikf, s1 = s[[1]]},
  ikf[set_] := Array[MapAt[#~Prepend~s1 &, set, #] &, Length@set];
  Join[
   Prepend[#, {s1}] & /@ KSetP[Rest@s, k - 1],
   Join @@ ikf /@ KSetP[Rest@s, k]
  ]
 ]

(r1 = KSetPartitions[Range@12, 4]) // Timing // First

(r2 = KSetP[Range@12, 4])          // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.529
>
> 1.139
> ```

The output is in a different order but it is equivalent:

```
Sort[Sort /@ r1] === Sort[Sort /@ r2]
```

> True

Comment: I think r1 = KSetPartitions needs to be renamed, as my output does not recognise the name?

Comment: @AlexanderKartun-Giles Sorry, I forgot to include ``Needs["Combinatorica`"]`` in my code; if you load that package first does the comparison work as expected?