# Splitting a list into 2 sublists in all possible ways

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

I have a list and I want to split it into 2 sublists in all possible ways
If

```
 S={1,2,3,4}
```

I should get

```
{{{1},{2,3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}}......{{1,4},{2,3}}....
```

I'm interested in the products of the sublists
so I want

```
 {{1,4},{2,3}}
```

to appear  in the result

but NOT

```
  {{2,3},{1,4}} or {{3,2},{1,4}}
```

to appear, too.

To make things clearer, for

```
S={1,2,3}
```

the result should be

```
{{{1},{2,3}},{{2},{1,3}},{{3},{1,2}}}
```

in any order you like

NOTE: Any element in the starting list can appear more than once

```
S={1,2,3,3,3,4}
```

is acceptable and the result should have the element

```
 {{1,2,3},{3,3,4}}
```

multiple times for ALL different 3's

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19672)?

Comment: What have you tried? TBH, this is one in a series of questions from you that seem more like a specification and a "do this for me" request, vs a "Here's my work so far"/"I'm having an issue implementing this", and this site is not a mechanical turk site. Add to this the very functionality requested *is an example in the documentation*. So, what have *you* tried?

Comment: That one splits the list into 2 with half lengths.I need all possible lengths...

Comment: @ciao Is this a personal attack? I've tried many things that doesn't work and read many related questions.I believe that my question has not an answer yet, so it will benefit others, too.I don't understant why you're being so rude

Comment: @Jenny_mathy I suggest you read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), in particular "a minimal working code example of your problem or your efforts" and "some proof of minimal Mathematica knowledge". This is *not* a tutorial site, this is *not* a "do this for me" site. Nothing personal about it.

Comment: I was hoping you'd start checking the "Related" links as well, which would have led you to e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8528)... now I'm no longer sure if you want `SetPartitions[]` or `KSetPartitions[]`.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, you just use

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

KSetPartitions[Range[1, 3, 1], 2]
```

---

## Mathematica 12.0

```mathematica
Needs[ "Combinatorica`"]



(* set partition *)
SetPartitions[{a, b, c}]  (* No constraints *)
RGFToSetPartition[#] & /@ RGFs[5]  (* Generate based on RGF, the result is consistent with the above, the order may be different *)
SetPartitionListViaRGF[5] (* Exactly the same as above, just wrapped again *)
KSetPartitions[3, 2]  (* Represents partitioning the set {1,2,3}, restricted to 2 parts *)
KSetPartitions[{a,b,c}, 2] (* Restricted to 2 parts *)

(* RGF related *)
RGFs[5]  (* Gives all RGF sequences of length 5 *)
SetPartitionToRGF[#] & /@ SetPartitions[5]  (* Generated based on sp, the result is consistent with the above, the order may be different *)
RandomRGF[5]  (* Equivalent to randomly selecting one from the above results *)
RGFToSetPartition[{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e}]  (* Mapping from RGF to SetPartition *)
RGFToSetPartition[{1, 2, 1, 2, 1}]  (* If the second parameter is missing, association [n] will be performed *)
RGFToSetPartition[{1, 2, 1, 2, 1},{a,b}]  (* Invalid inputs will not calculate results *) 

(* Functions with rank are basically not needed to be looked at, if you know how to write [[]] *)
RankSetPartition[#] & /@ SetPartitions[4]  (* This result is Range[0, 14] *)
```

## Reference

[Restricted growth function(RGF) patterns and statistics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04807.pdf)

[Partitions and Compositions - Wolfram Mathematica Official Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v12/Combinatorica/guide/PartitionsAndCompositions.html)

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if I have misunderstood.
Perhaps,

```
f[u_] := 
 Module[{i = IntegerDigits[Range[2^Length[u] - 2], 2, Length[u]]},
  DeleteDuplicates[{Pick[u, #, 0], Pick[u, #, 1]} & /@ 
    i, #1 == Reverse[#2] &]]
```

For example:

```
Table[{j, f[j]}, {j, {Range[3], Range[4], {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4}}}] // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All]
```

[image]