# Partition a set of n objects into k subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, partitions, sets

Is there some function recently added to *Mathematica* that facilitates forming all partitions of a *n*-element set into *k* subsets?

In other words, something that easily gives the same thing as what `` Combinatorica`KSetPartitions `` does?

I'm aware of the defined function `KSetP` at [Partition a set into $k$ non-empty subsets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19672/partition-a-set-into-k-non-empty-subsets), but that has quite a bit of code.

My query here is asking for something at a higher level than the aforementioned function `KSetP` that is made possible by some built-in function either that was recently added to *Mathematica* or was previously available but was not exploited in `KSetP`.

Comment: How big is your `n` likely to be? For small `n` there may be something simpler, but I would guess that since there are $2^n$ subsets, it quickly becomes tricky to keep the computational costs down.

Comment: @JasonB.: I referenced that; but please look at the framing of my question again.

Comment: @aardvark2012: I want something that works for general *n*. The issue is whether some built-in function, especially one added recently, can take care of a lot more of the work at a lower level, hence no need to do the detailed coding shown for `kSetP`.

Comment: @murray - I don't see the distinction really.  Is there a built in function to do this?  I can't find it if there is.  You say the `KSetP` function has quite a bit of code, but it's definition is only 11 lines.

Comment: There are more answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/finding-all-partitions-of-a-set), one of which may be "at a higher level".