# Generating partitions of a set with a specified size of the parts

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, combinatorics

I tried the following (inspired by the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/finding-all-partitions-of-a-set))

```
myList = {a, b, c};
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
SetPartitions[myList]
```

and I got this answer,

```
{{{a, b, c}}, {{a}, {b, c}}, {{a, b}, {c}}, {{a,c}, {b}}, {{a}, {b}, {c}}}
```

I checked the documentation of KSetpartitions also.

- But where and how do I specify it if I say want only partitions in say parts of size 2 (Wick's theorem!) ? (..of course it will have to give a null result if the total number of elements of the starting set is an odd number..)

Comment: Isn't there just one result, given by `Partition[myList, 2]`?

Comment: If I understand you I believe this question is answered here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3044/121 Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The "more economic" solution of Istvan doesn't seem to work. I tried it on a set of 4 elements and it failed.

Comment: @wxffles I don't want all subsets of size 2. I want all partitions such that all parts are of size 2.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Rojo's answer looks to be what I want but I don't understand how to give the set and the part length input to it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I could get Rojo's answer to work - but its like mumbo-jumbo to me who has no clue how to do programming on Mathematica! Its as good as using some package! I wish i could understand Rojo's syntax and method!

Comment: @user6818 since Rojo's code is doing what you need I'm going to close this question with a link to that one, to keep things organized.  I too found Rojo's function hard to understand at first, not the syntax but the underlying algorithm.  He explained it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3837894#3837894).  If you have question about the syntax ask focused questions in [the main chat room.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica).  BTW, F1 will bring up help for the token at the location of the cursor, and see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121