# Seeking a way to generate sequential partitions of a list using built in or Combinatorica functions

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, partitions, combinatorica

This code generates all "sequential partitions" of a list:

```
testlist = {a, b, c, d, e};
w = Length[testlist];
breakpoints = Map[Join[#, {w}] &, Subsets[Range[w - 1]]];
partitionfrombreakpoints[breakpointlist_] := 
  Prepend[Map[
    Take[testlist, {breakpointlist[[#]] + 1, 
       breakpointlist[[# + 1]]}] &, 
    Range[Length[breakpointlist] - 1]], 
   Take[testlist, {1, breakpointlist[[1]]}]];
Print[Grid[Map[partitionfrombreakpoints, breakpoints]]];
```

Like so:

```
{a,b,c,d,e}             
{a} {b,c,d,e}           
{a,b}   {c,d,e}         
{a,b,c} {d,e}           
{a,b,c,d}   {e}         
{a} {b} {c,d,e}     
{a} {b,c}   {d,e}       
{a} {b,c,d} {e}     
{a,b}   {c} {d,e}       
{a,b}   {c,d}   {e}     
{a,b,c} {d} {e}     
{a} {b} {c} {d,e}   
{a} {b} {c,d}   {e} 
{a} {b,c}   {d} {e} 
{a,b}   {c} {d} {e} 
{a} {b} {c} {d} {e}
```

I have tried to use Partitions, SetPartitions, Compositions and Permutations to achieve the same result more elegantly, but without success. Can anyone help, please ?

Comment: Your question implies you have a working code, but the code in the question is full of errors, can you please [edit] your question?

Comment: My apologies, rhermans. The code seems to work fine for me. I have just added the output.

Comment: Does it work for you with a fresh kernel? what are you expecting from `Subsets[4]`?

Comment: Aha ! No ! Perhaps Subsets belongs in the Combinatorica package. I will check now.

Comment: Im Mma 10.3 I get: *Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.* Which version are you using?

Comment: Yes - that was the problem. Sorry about that. I have edited the code in my question to include loading Combinatorica. Presumably `Subsets has another definition in Combinatorica. I am using version 9 of Mathematica. The code now works for me, even with a fresh kernel. Does the code run for you in v. 10.3, in spite of the warning about Combinatorica ?

Comment: This is strange, I seem to remember reading in some documentation that `Subsets[n]` is equivalent to `Subsets[Range[n]]`, but now I cannot find it. In any case, that is exactly how it works for me.

Comment: I have edited the code, replacing Subsets[n] by Subsets[Range[n]], so it now no longer depends on the Combinatorica package.

Comment: Also see: [(8528)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8528/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[{a, b, c, d, e}, #] & /@
         Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[5], 1]
```

About `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``: I have read about it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7512/23402).

Comment: Thank you very much Alexey, and also @rhermans, march and eldo !

Answer (score 3):

Possible partitions for a list with 5 elements:

```
    n = 5;
    Union@Select[Tuples[#, Length@#], Total@# == n &] & /@ 
       IntegerPartitions[n] // Sort // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Using integer partitions is clever (+1)! Now, how to use the resulting list to break up `{a, b, c, d, e}` into its list partitions?

Comment: @march, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I'd seen that before (complete with many upvotes) but had completely forgotten about it :)

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

```
f[list_] := 
 With[{part = 
    Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[list]], 1]},
  Table[
   First@Last@
     Reap[FoldList[(Sow[First[#]]; Last[#]) &@*TakeDrop, list, p]]
   , {p, part}]
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[{a, b, c, d, e}] // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Option 2

```
PartitionRagged[vec_, lens_] := 
 MapThread[vec[[#1 ;; #2]] &, 
  With[{a = Accumulate[lens]}, {a - lens + 1, a}]]

f2[list_] := 
 PartitionRagged[list, #] & /@ 
  Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[list]], 1]
```

Comment: Thank you rhermans. The code is generating errors for me. Syntax::sntxf: "(Sow[First[#]];Last[#])&@" cannot be followed by "*TakeDrop".

Comment: Did you try with a fresh kernel? What is the error message?

Comment: Yes, I tried with a fresh kernel. The @ is highlighted and the first error message is Syntax::sntxf: "(Sow[First[#]];Last[#])&@" cannot be followed by "*TakeDrop".

Comment: Strange, try replacing by `Composition[(Sow[First[#]]; Last[#]) & , TakeDrop]`. The thing is that v9 has a different take on `Composition` or `Compose`

Comment: Thank you, I will certainly look into this if I get a chance. Meanwhile I'll go with Alexey's answer. Many thanks again for your help.