# Add elements of a list to sublists of another list, such that each of these sublists has minimum edges in the corresponding graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I've got a graph `g` with the following adjacency matrix:

```
adj = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
       {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
       {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
       {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 
       {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}};

g = AdjacencyGraph[adj, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Now I have list `A`, which contains mutually disjoint sets of vertices, such that no two vertices in one of the sets share an edge:

```
A = {{3, 4, 8}, {1, 5, 10}}
```

In other words, the subgraphs spanned by each of these subsets contain no edges.

And I've also got a list `B` which contains the remaining vertices:

```
B = {2, 6, 7, 9}
```

Now I want to add the vertices from `B` to the subsets in `A` such that the total number of edges in the subgraphs spanned by the resulting subsets is minimal. For example, if I were to add `2` to the set `{3, 4, 8}` the resulting subgraph would contain a single edge, but adding it to `{1, 5, 10}` instead would result in a subgraph with two edges.

For this example, the optimal solution is to add `2` and `7` to the first set, and `6` and `9` to the second, resulting in only 9 edges in both subgraphs together.

Is there a simple and efficient way to compute an optimal solution this problem?

Comment: Thank you very much Martin; Now it looks much better indeed!

Answer (score 2):

A brute-force approach:

```
ClearAll[objF]
adjm = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
        {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}};

aa = {{3, 4, 8}, {1, 5, 10}};
bb = {2, 6, 7, 9};

ag = AdjacencyGraph[adjm, VertexLabels->"Name", VertexStyle->Large, ImagePadding->20];

cc = {Join[aa[[1]], #], Join[aa[[2]], Complement[bb, #]]} & /@ Subsets[bb];

objF[g_] := EdgeCount[Subgraph[g, #[[1]]]] + EdgeCount[Subgraph[g, #[[2]]]] &;

HighlightGraph[ag, Join[Style[#, Green] & /@ aa[[1]], Style[#, Red] & /@ aa[[2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 dd = MinimalBy[cc, objF[ag]][[1]]
```

> {{3, 4, 8, 2, 7}, {1, 5, 10, 6, 9}}

```
 objF[ag]@dd
```

> 9

```
HighlightGraph[ag, Join[Style[#, Green] & /@ dd[[1]], Style[#, Red] & /@ dd[[2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
HighlightGraph[ag, Join[Style[#, Thick, Green] & /@ EdgeList[Subgraph[ag, dd[[1]]]], 
   Style[#, Thick, Red] & /@ EdgeList[Subgraph[ag, dd[[2]]]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is actually what I did just now to figure out the reference solution, but note that using `Subsets` and `Complement` doesn't generalise if there are more than two sets in `A` (although it's not clear whether that's a possibility). If it is, then one would need option three from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8529/2305), filtered for the right number of partitions.

Comment: Thank you very much kglr for your extensive answer. I did it with a nested Do loop; however, your way looks more professional and efficient. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Marilla It's nice and clean but it's certainly not efficient (which is implied by kglr's first three words). This will look at all `|B|^|A|` possible solutions, and each of them is at least linear in the size of the graph, so this will be infeasible once your graph gets bigger.

Comment: @Martin,  thanks for the link to J.M.'s answer. Did think about generalization to arbitrary number of lists in `aa`,  but got lazy:)

Answer (score 0):

Compute possible partitions:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
part = Join[KSetPartitions[bb, Length[aa]], Permutations[Append[ConstantArray[{}, Length[aa] - 1], bb]]]

MinimalBy[part, 
 Total[MapThread[EdgeCount[Subgraph[g, Join[#1, #2]]] &, {aa, #}]] &]
```

> {{{2, 7}, {6, 9}}}