# Groupings of the Elements of a List with at Most $k$ Elements

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions, gathering

Given a list with $n$ elements and an integer $k$ I want to get a list with all possible groupings of these n elements in sets with at most k elements. For example, given $n=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $k=3$ I want

$$S=\{P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5,P_6,P_7,P_8,P_9,P_{10},P_{11}\}$$

where

$$P_1=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}\\ P_2=\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}\\ P_3=\{\{1,3\},\{2\},\{4\}\}\\P_4=\{\{1,4\},\{2\},\{3\}\}\\ P_5=\{\{2,3\},\{1\},\{4\}\}\\P_6=\{\{2,4\},\{1\},\{3\}\}\\ P_7=\{\{3,4\},\{1\},\{2\}\}\\P_8=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}\\ P_9=\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}\\P_{10}=\{\{1,2,3\},\{4\}\}\\P_{11}=\{\{1,2,4\},\{3\}\}\\P_{12}=\{\{1,3,4\},\{2\}\}\\P_{13}=\{\{2,3,4\},\{1\}\}$$

Comment: Do you also already have some code you tried?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8528).

Comment: @Davi Bastos Hmm. Do I get something wrong or are you missing the partitions into exactly two sets with two elements each?

Comment: Johu, I did a code, but using Pyhton... rs  
J.M I tried to find a similar question but I didn't, but thanks for the link!
Henrik Schumacker Yes, I missed them, I should edit and include them, right?
Thanks all! :)

Answer (score 3):

Adapting the code linked by J.M.:

```
groupings[n_, k_] := Module[{list, bla, blubb},
   list = Range[n];
   bla = Internal`PartitionRagged[list, #] & /@ IntegerPartitions[n, n, Range[k]];
   blubb = Flatten[PermutationReplace[#, Permutations[list]] & /@ bla, 1];
   DeleteDuplicates[Sort[Sort /@ Map[Sort, blubb, {2}]]]
   ];

groupings[4, 3]
```

> {
>
> {{1}, {2, 3, 4}},
>
> {{2}, {1, 3, 4}},
>
> {{3}, {1, 2, 4}},
>
> {{4}, {1, 2,3}},
>
> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}},
>
> {{1, 3}, {2, 4}},
>
> {{1, 4}, {2, 3}},
>
> {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}},
>
> {{1}, {3}, {2, 4}},
>
> {{1}, {4}, {2, 3}},
>
> {{2}, {3}, {1, 4}},
>
> {{2}, {4}, {1, 3}},
>
> {{3}, {4}, {1, 2}},
>
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}
>
> }

Alternatively, using `` "Combinatorica`" `` (probably more efficient):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
Select[
 SetPartitions[Range[4]],
 Max[Length /@ #] <= 3 &
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

A modification of [Finding all partitions of a set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/finding-all-partitions-of-a-set/8532#8532), itself based on [`BellList` from Robert M. Dickau](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110063111/http://mathforum.org/advanced/robertd/bell.html)

```
partition[{x_}, k_] := {{{x}}}

partition[{r__, x_}, k_] :=
 Join @@ (
    ReplaceList[
      #,
      {b___, {S : Repeated[_, k - 1]}, a___} | {b__} :> {b, {S, x}, a}
    ] & /@ partition[{r}, k]
 )

partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 3]
```