# Construct an infix operation from a list

Tags: expression-manipulation

Inspired by this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15021/52), if I have a list

```
{a, p, b, q, c}
```

where `p` and `q` are binary operators, such as `Plus` and `Times`, how would I construct the expression

```
a ~ p ~ b ~ q ~ c
```

and execute it?

Obviously, the solution proposed in the other question of constructing it via strings is the most straightforward approach, but I would like to know if the infix formulation, above, is doable without resorting to string manipulation.

Comment: Does `Hold[{a, Plus, b, Times, c}] //. {PatternSequence[a_, p_, b_, c___]} :> {p[a, b], c}` work?

Comment: @J.M. it looks like it does. I expected that to take a little longer, but I've been up for quite a while now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two variants:

```
(* left-associative *)
Hold[a, Times, b, Plus, c, Subtract, f] //. f_[a_, p_, b_, c___] :> f[p[a, b], c]
 (* Hold[(a b + c) - f] *)

(* right-associative *)
Hold[a, Times, b, Plus, c, Subtract, f] //. f_[c___, a_, p_, b_] :> f[c, p[a, b]]
 (* Hold[a (b + (c - f))] *)
```

after which one can apply `ReleaseHold[]`...

Answer (score 6):

Looks like I'm late to the party but I can still have fun with the existing answers.

Terse form of István's method:

```
x = {a, p, b, q, c, r, d, s, e};

First@Nest[{#2[#, #3], ##4} & @@ # &, x, (Length@x - 1)/2]
```

With [two-parameter `Fold` syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121) kguler's `foldF` can be written:

```
Fold[{##} /. {{x_, f_}, y_} :> x ~f~ y &, #] &
```

Last but not least a method based on Rojo's answer:

```
infixate =
  Module[{f},
    SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
    f @@ # //. {f@i_ :> i, f[a1__, h_, a2_] :> h[f@a1, a2]}
  ] &;

{a, p, b} // infixate
```

> ```
> p[a, b]
> ```

```
Hold[a, Print, 2 + 2, q, 8/4, r, d, Hold, e] // infixate
```

> ```
> Hold[r[q[Print[a, 2 + 2], 8/4], d], e]
> ```

Here's one more I couldn't pass by, even though it is string-based:

```
x = {a, Times, b, Plus, c, Subtract, f};

ToExpression@ToString@Row[x, "~"]
```

> ```
> a b + c - f
> ```

Comment: `Quotient[]` is nice: `First@Nest[{#2[#, #3], ##4} & @@ # &, x, Length@x ~Quotient~ 2]`

Comment: I was hoping you'd join the party. Now I have to decide on a winner.

Comment: @rcollyer J.M.'s, clearly, IMHO.

Comment: Since we all know you just loooooove infix and are always keen to save a few characters, why not try, instead of `Module`/`SetAttributes`, `f ~Unique~ {HoldAll, Temporary}`... (and +1, of course!)

Comment: @Oleksandr Interesting proposition. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
f[{i_}] := i;
f[{a1__, h_, a2_}] := h[f[{a1}], a2]
```

So

```
{a, p, b, q, c}//f

(* q[p[a, b], c] *)
```

It doesn't respect holding attributes, but `Plus` and `Times` don't hold their arguments anyway

Answer (score 3):

Implementation with `Nest`. Note, that this version is left-associative, and requires an input list of $2n+1$ elements (with $n$ infix operators):

```
x = {a, p, b, q, c, r, d, s, e};

First@Nest[{#[[2]][#[[1]], #[[3]]], Sequence @@ Drop[#, 3]} &, x, (Length@x - 1)/2]
```

> ```
> s[r[q[p[a, b], c], d], e]
> ```

Right-associative:

```
First@Nest[{Sequence @@ Drop[#, -3], #[[-2]][#[[-3]], #[[-1]]]} &, x, (Length@x - 1)/2]
```

> ```
> p[a, q[b, r[c, s[d, e]]]]
> ```

Comment: Alternatively: `First @ Nest[Prepend[Drop[#, 3], #[[1]] ~#[[2]]~ #[[3]]] &, x, Quotient[Length @ x, 2]]` and `First @ Nest[Append[Drop[#, -3], #[[-3]] ~#[[-2]]~ #[[-1]]] &, x, Quotient[Length @ x, 2]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
 foldF = Fold[{#1, #2} /. {{x_, f_}, y_} :> f[x, y] &, First@#, Rest@#] &;
 foldF /@ {{a, p, b, q, c, r, d, s, e},
     {a, Times, b, Plus, c, Subtract, d, Divide, e},
     {2, Times, 3, Plus, 4, Subtract, 5, Divide, 2}}
 (* {s[r[q[p[a,b],c],d],e], (a*b+c-d)/e, 5/2} *)
```

---

```
  ClearAll[fldInfiX, infiX, evaluateF];
  evaluateF = # //. Infix[x__] :> x &;
  infiX[x_] := x;
  infiX[f_[x_, y_]] := Infix[f[x, y]];
  fldInfiX = Function[{lst}, Fold[{#1, #2} /. {{x_, f_}, y_} :> infiX[f[x, y]] &,
       First@lst, Rest@lst]];
  fldInfiX /@ {{a, op1, b, op2, c},
     {a, Times, b, Plus, c}, {1, Times, 2, Plus, 3},
    {5, Subtract, 2, Plus, 12, Divide, 2}}
  (* {(a~op1~b)~op2~c, c~Plus~(a~Times~b), 5, 15~Rational~2}  *)
  evaluateF /@ %
  (* {op2[op1[a, b], c], a*b + c, 5, 15/2}  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformulate the question: you can't do this generally without declaring the precedence of p and q.  If p takes precedence of q, your expression is fully represented as

```
{{a,p,b},q,c}
```

otherwise it is

```
{a,p,{b,q,c}}
```

Once you've done that, use this replacement:

```
{a, p, {b, q, c}} //. {x_, f_, y_} -> Infix@f[x, y]
{{a, p, b}, q, c} //. {x_, f_, y_} -> Infix@f[x, y]
```

For this output:

```
a~p~(b~q~c)
(a~p~b)~q~c
```

What you probably want though, is the Notations package:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\"~p~\""], p]
InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\"~q~\""], q]
```

Then, when you enter

```
p[a, q[b,c]]
```

the output is automatically

```
a ~p~ (b ~q~ c)
```

but the internal representation is still p[a, q[b,c]].