# How can I convert a list to an expression?

Tags: programming, algebra

For example, I have the following list:

{x1,op1,x2,op2,x3,op3,...}

And I would like to convert the list to the following expression:

x1 op1 x2 op2 x3 op3 ...

Comment: That's just `Times @@ {x1, op1, x2, op2, x3, op3}`.  I'm sure this question has been asked before, and it's pretty easily found in the documentation as well.  I am going to close it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I assume the op1, op2 etc. stand for operator 1, operator 2 etc. so this changes the intention of the question slightly.

Comment: @Sjoerd In that case is a duplicate of [(15032)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15032/121).