# Duplicate mapped elements in Riffle

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the best way to do this?

in:

```
{a, b, c}
{d, {e, f}, g}
```

out:

```
{{a, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, g}}
```

---

```
If[Length[#[[2]]] > 0, Transpose[{Table[#[[1]], {x, Length[#[[2]]]}], #[[2]]}], #] 
& /@ Partition[Riffle[{a, b, c}, {d, {e, f}, g}], 2]
```

seems a bit longwinded.

Comment: Just for fun, not good for numbers :) : `Flatten[MapThread[ArcTan, {{a, b, c}, {d, {e, f}, g}}]] /. 
 ArcTan -> List`.

Comment: @Kuba You jogged a memory.  I think this question is a duplicate.  I *remember* writing this before:  `Quiet@Re[{a, b, c}, {d, {e, f}, g}] /. Re -> List`.  Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Related: [(17400)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17400/121), and my answer with `Re`: [(28693)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28693/121).  Sadly no votes. :'-(

Comment: This question is *almost* a duplicate of 17400 linked above, but flat output is desired.  I don't know if that is enough to keep this open or not.  I'll let the community votes decide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
l1 = {a, b, c};
l2 = {d, {e, f}, g};

Partition[Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[{l1, l2}]], 2]
```

> {{a, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, g}}

or

```
(## & @@ Thread @ #) & /@ Thread[{l1, l2}]
```

> {{a, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, g}}

Comment: very nice  .....:)

Answer (score 8):

Using [undocumented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29168/121) `Function` syntax, [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), and v10 [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) syntax:

```
fn1 = #[[2, 1]] & @* Reap @* Function[, Sow[{##}], Listable];

fn1[{a, b, c}, {d, {e, f}, g}]
```

> ```
> {{a, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, g}}
> ```

This works at deeper levels as well:

```
fn1[{a, b, c}, {d, {{e1, e2}, f}, g}]
```

> ```
> {{a, d}, {b, e1}, {b, e2}, {b, f}, {c, g}}
> ```

Another method without the undocumented functionality:

```
With[{h = Unique["h", Listable]},
  fn2 = Cases[h[##], h[e__] :> {e}, -1] &
]
```

Test:

```
fn2[{a, b, c}, {d, {{e1, e2}, f}, g}]
```

> ```
> {{a, d}, {b, e1}, {b, e2}, {b, f}, {c, g}}
> ```

Comment: great :) Its a bit strange though because the double slot is pink in my Mathematica ... it works though!

Comment: @martin Please see the alternative I added.

Comment: Nice alternative to using `SetAttributes` there, I'll have to remember that!

Comment: @Simon Thank Oleksandr: [(15032)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15032/construct-an-infix-operation-from-a-list#comment44674_15081)

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
ff = Flatten[#, 1] &; 
ff@MapThread[Function[{u, v}, {u, #} & /@ ff[{v}]], {{a, b, c}, {x, {y, u}, z}}]

(* {{a, x}, {b, y}, {b, u}, {c, z}}*)
```

Comment: that's a bit more elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

```
l1 = {a, b, c};
l2 = {d, {e, f}, g};    
Level[Thread[{#, #2}] & @@@ Transpose[{l1, l2}], {-2}]
(*{{a, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, g}}*)
```

Comment: This does assume that list elements are atomic, but +1.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReplaceAll` with `Splice` (since V. 13.1)

```
l1 = {a, b, c};
l2 = {d, {e, f}, g};

Transpose[{l1, l2}] /. {a_, {b_, c_}} :> Splice[{{a, b}, {a, c}}]
```

{{a, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, g}}

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

```
MapThread[Thread@*List,{l1,l2}]//FlattenAt[2]

(* {{a,d},{b,e},{b,f},{c,g}} *)
```

Or

```
Level[MapThread[Thread@*List,{l1,l2}],{-2}]

(* {{a,d},{b,e},{b,f},{c,g}} *)
```

---

**Original Answer**

```
MapThread[Thread[Distribute[{##}]]&,{l1,l2}]//FlattenAt[2]

(* {{a,d},{b,e},{b,f},{c,g}} *)
```

Or

```
Level[MapThread[Thread[Distribute[{##}]]&,{l1,l2}],{-2}]

(* {{a,d},{b,e},{b,f},{c,g}} *)
```