# Solving calculation puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, arithmetic, puzzle

I recently got asked how to achieve a result of `100` only using the numbers `{1,7,7,7,7}` (the number 1 can be used only once and the number 7 can be used four times at maximum so not every number have to be used) and the operations `+, -, *, /` and also brackets. So I tried many different calculations and never got to `100`. Of course I cant try all the possible combinations so I thought I could use Mathematica to see wether this is possible or not. One idea would be to generate a set with all numbers (rather integers) we could get from all possible combinations and the other idea would be to find an explicit expression to calculate the result from the given numbers.

Examples:

`7*7+7*7+1 = 99`

`7*(7+1)+7 = 63`

`7*(7+1)+7*7 = 105`

`((7 + 7)/7)*(7 + 1) = 16`

`7*7*(7/7 + 1) = 98`

Comment: Cool ideas, have you try to implement them?

Comment: Do we use each operator only once?

Comment: You can use each operator as often as you want.

Comment: [Two](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15021) [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140348) questions.

Comment: easy: 7*7+7*7+1+1

Comment: I wrote `{1,7,7,7,7}` instead of `{1,7}` to express that the number 1 can only be used once and the number 7 can be used four times. So 7*7+7*7+1+1 is not valid.

Comment: can 7 be used 3 times or 2 times? does it have to be used four times?

Comment: Yes. Im gonna edit the question with some examples to make it easier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all ways to make 21 by using each of 1, 5, 6 and 7 once, using the four primary binary operations (+, -, \*, /)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140348/find-all-ways-to-make-21-by-using-each-of-1-5-6-and-7-once-using-the-four-pri)

Answer (score 6):

Here are all $4$ solutions to the puzzle

[image]

## Technique #1

[heavily plagiarizing this excellent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140350/36681)

Apparently [`Groupings`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings.html) is the tool for the job!

```
ans = Groupings[
                 Permutations[{7, 7, 7, 7, 1}]~Join~Permutations[{7, 7, 7, 1}]
               , {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide} -> 2
               , HoldForm
       ];
Grid[
     Thread[{Quiet[Select[ans, ReleaseHold[#] == 100 &]]} ] 
     , Frame -> All
     , FrameStyle -> Red
 ]
```