# Automating interesting ways to write 2023

Tags: functions, function-construction, code-request, factorization

Inspired by [*Interesting ways to write 2023*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608782/interesting-ways-to-write-2023#4608782), I was wondering if there are ways to automate the search for results using MMA.

I tried

```
  PowersRepresentations[2023, 3, 2]
```

However, it did not provide output ($2023$ is not a number that can written as the sum of three squares).

However,

```
  PowersRepresentations[2023, 4, 2]
```

Provides many examples of the sum of four squares.

Are there any other commands in Mathematica to provide solutions or a way to automate searching some out that are not the plethora of the above?

Happy New Year to all!

**Update**

I found this interesting code (I cannot decode it) at [*Write a Number as a Fibonacci Sum*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15999/write-a-number-as-a-fibonacci-sum), just enter $2023$ at the prompt.

```
  i=Input[];#~Row~"+"&/@Select[If[#>i,Subsets@{##},#0[#+#2,##]]&[2,1],Tr@#==i&]//Column
```

Comment: Best wishes for a happy new year! I guess we are looking for generic ways to represent `2023` and so does `IntegerPartitions[2023]` count?

Comment: @bmf: Thanks for the well wishes. My computer is chugging away and crashed with that command. The answer is likely yes as I was just looking for results that are different the sum of four squares.

Comment: There was also some intense integration formulas for 2019 that one might adapt to 2023 : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3058069/1049002

Comment: [Insert +, −, ×, /, (, ) into 123456789 to make it equal to 100](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15021/2090)

Comment: For a random partition: `ResourceFunction["RandomIntegerPartition"][2023]`

Comment: @userrandrand: Excellent - I am always amazed at the number of interesting functions built into MMA. I wish I could spend lots of time just studying them! Happy new year!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would like to point out `FrobeniusSolve`, e.g. this yields nonnegative solutions $(x_1,x_2)$ of this equation $20 x_1 +23 x_2 =2023$

```
FrobeniusSolve[{20, 23}, 2023]
```

> ```
> {{8, 81}, {31, 61}, {54, 41}, {77, 21}, {100, 1}}
> ```

`FrobeniusSolve`  yields an unbounded set (it is finite but sometimes enormous)  of possibilites of representing a given number, e.g.

```
FrobeniusSolve[{2, 3, 5, 7}, 2023] // Length
```

> ```
> 6653921
> ```

**Edit**

`FrobeniusSolve` as well as `Reduce`, `Solve` and `FindInstance` provide huge set of variations of the method mentioned above. However we can exploit quite a different approach.

```
FactorInteger[2023, GaussianIntegers -> True]
```

> ```
> {{-1, 1}, {1 + 4 I, 2}, {4 + I, 2}, {7, 1}}
> ```

and so with `GaussianIntegers` we can write:

```
-1 (1 + 4 I)^2 (4 + I)^2 7
```

> ```
> 2023
> ```

Similarily with integer factorization ($2023=7\cdot 17^2$) we can find examples of integers for which the geometric mean provides $2023$

```
GeometricMean /@ {{833, 4913}, {49, 83521}, {119, 34391}}
```

> ```
>  {2023, 2023, 2023}
> ```

There are plenty of analytic methods, e.g.

summation of the harmonic series:

```
N[ HarmonicNumber[21235148975836561123684489978 10^850], 32]
```

> ```
> 2023.0000000000000000000000000000
> ```

Imaginary part of the argument of the Riemann Zeta function on the critical line between $1538$-th and $1539$-th zero is $2023$:

```
{Ceiling @ Im @ ZetaZero @ 1538,  Floor @ Im @ ZetaZero @ 1539}
```

> ```
>  { 2023, 2023}
> ```

Curiously we can also express the number symetrically with three sevens

```
Prime[7] 7 Prime[7]
```

> ```
> 2023
> ```

Comment: (+1) and I am very impressed that `FrobeniusSolve[{2, 3, 5, 7}, 2023]` gives a result and does not crash the kernel!

Comment: @Artes: Very creative updates!

Answer (score 11):

Happy new year!

```
IntegerDigits[2023, 2]
```

> `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}`

Edit: another interesting way

```
NumberExpand[2023, base]
```

and then we can specify the base. An example is to consider the base of 5

```
NumberExpand[2023, 5]
```

> `{1875, 125, 0, 20, 3}`

Edit 2:

```
FactorInteger[2023]
```

> `{{7, 1}, {17, 2}}`

Comment: Happy new year, mate! `1012^2 - 1011^2` :-)

Comment: Happy new year! Best wishes :-) That's a nice one btw

Comment: For fun and curiosity here is an image of the output of a cellular automaton with rule 110 where the initial condition is the binary representation of 2023 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RviWE.png

Comment: @userrandrand Seems like a complicated tetris structure :)

Answer (score 11):

I thought it could be nice to use different domains of Mathematica to represent 2023 in different ways.

**Outline:**

- **Entities**
- **Polynomial algebra**
- **Linguistic Data**
- **Number theory**
- **Text analysis**
- **Special functions**
- **Plotting**

For the fun of it, here is the outline as an unordered wordcloud with [`DropShadowing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DropShadowing.html) (version 13.1) :

**Note :** Text placement might differ each time as it is random.

```
WordCloud[{"Entities", "Polynomial algebra", "Linguistic data", 
   "Number theory", "Text analysis", "Special functions", "Plotting", 
   Rotate["2023", Pi/3]}] /. 
 Graphics[{a_, b___}, c___] :> Graphics[{DropShadowing[], a, b}, c]
```

[image]

#### Entities

**Write 2023 as the approximate ratio between the mass of an exoplanet and that of earth**.

Mass of the earth:

```
earthMass = 
  Entity["Planet", "Earth"][EntityProperty["Planet", "Mass"]];
```

The exoplanets that have a mass that is roughly 2023 times that of the earth :

```
FilteredEntityClass["Exoplanet", 
  EntityFunction[e, 
   Abs[e["Mass"]/(2023*earthMass) - 1] < 0.1]] // EntityList
```

[image]

#### Polynomial algebra

**Find an expression for 2023 in terms of radicals**.

Using the general formula for a quartic:

```
sol = Solve[x^4 + a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d == 0, x];
```

Considering a random monic polynomial that has root 2023:

```
coefrule = {d, c, b, a} -> (Drop[#, -1] &)@
    CoefficientList[(RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 3] . x^Range[0, 2] + 
        x^3)*(x - 2023), x] // Thread
```

Thus another representation of 2023 that most people might be less familar with is :

$$2023=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(49748794692 \sqrt{705}-1342923812836\right)}-\frac{24470164}{3} (-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{1342923812836-49748794692 \sqrt{705}}}+\frac{3072436}{3}}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(49748794692 \sqrt{705}-1342923812836\right)}+\frac{1}{3} (-1)^{2/3} 24470164 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{1342923812836-49748794692 \sqrt{705}}}+\frac{6144872}{3}+\frac{2072863396}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(49748794692 \sqrt{705}-1342923812836\right)}-\frac{24470164}{3} (-1)^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{1342923812836-49748794692 \sqrt{705}}}+\frac{3072436}{3}}}}+505$$

#### Linguistic data

**Write the year 2023 in some of the most spoken languages**.

First find the the top 10 most spoken languages. I used free form with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> followed by top 10 most spoken languages. After applying `EntityList` we have:

[image]

Unfortunately the code below does not work with a lot of languages so I took the top 20 most spoken an extracted the cases that worked.

```
languages = 
 EntityClass[
   "Language", {EntityProperty["Language", "TotalSpeakers"] -> 
     TakeLargest[20]}] // EntityList
```

Then we use [`IntegerName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html) to write the year 2023 and we also use [`Transliterate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transliterate.html) to write the word in ASCII format:

```
(
languages
//Map[{CommonName@#,
        IntegerName[2023,
                    "Year",
                    Language->#]
        //{Identity,Transliterate}//Through
        //Splice
    }&]
//Quiet
//DeleteCases[_?(Not@*FreeQ[_IntegerName])]
)
```

Unfortunately the output seemed to have errors with east asian languages so I removed those manually. I also used TraditionalForm as it looked nicer.

[image]

**Curated version**

There seems to be an error for the name for 2023 in french (but maybe that is how it is pronounced in Canada not sure). Hence, I changed it in the table below. Upon request I also added Greek. Greek is not given in the dropdown menu when typing a language with `IntegerName` but it still works with `IntegerName[2023, "Year", Language -> "Greek"]`.  Feel free to leave a comment with the translation in your language.

[image]

#### Number theory

**Characterize 2023 as the unique number specifying a number theory related property**

2023 is the only [lucky number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LuckyNumber.html) of this decade.

The list of lucky numbers lower than a certain integer can be found using the resource function [LuckyNumbers](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/LuckyNumbers/). The list below shows the last 2 before 2030.

```
ResourceFunction["LuckyNumbers"][2030][[-2 ;; -1]]
(* {2019, 2023} *)
```

#### Text analysis

**Characterize 2023 as the year where certain events are planned to occur**.

One can use the wikipedia page on 2023 :

```
data = WikipediaData["2023"];
```

Then we can extract the list of events using:

```
TextSentences[StringExtract[data, "==" -> 5]]
```

**Bonus:** For a given event in that list we can get a data set of text contents using [`TextContents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextContents.html) and we can ask questions about the event from the text content using [`FindTextualAnswer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindTextualAnswer.html).

#### Special functions

**Write 2023 as  a MeijerG function evaluated on an explicit argument**.

Consider a simple function and find the MeijerG representation:

```
expression=1/(1 + x^2) // MeijerGReduce[#, x] &
```

Find a value for `x` where the function is equal to 2023 :

```
sol = Solve[1/(1 + x^2) == 2023][[1]]
```

The result :

```
expression /. sol
```

$$\text{MeijerG}\left[\{\{0\},\{\}\},\{\{0\},\{\}\},-\frac{2022}{2023}\right]$$

#### Plotting

**Write 2023 as the limit of a sequence and plot that sequence to visualize the limit and accuracy**

Consider a continued fraction representation of 2023 as `Exp[ContinuedFraction[Log[2023]]]`. In the following we will plot the convergence of the sequence `u[n]=Exp[ContinuedFraction[Log[2023]],n]` using the resource function [MultipleAxesPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultipleAxesPlot).

Visualizing the sequence :

```
digits = ContinuedFraction[Log[2023], 20];

Table[digits[[1]] + 
     ContinuedFractionK[(HoldForm /@ digits)[[k]], {k, 2, l}], {l, 1, 
     7}] // Map[Exp] // Quiet // TraditionalForm
```

$$\left\{e^7,e^{7+\frac{1}{1}},e^{7+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}},e^{7+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}}},e^{7+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}}}},e^{7+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}}}}}},e^{7+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1}}}}}}}\right\}$$

Interpolate the sequence and `Log10` of the relative error with respect to the limit:

```
curves = 
  Exp@Convergents[Log[2023], 20] // {Interpolation, 
     Interpolation[Log10[Abs[#/2023 - 1]] ] &} // Through;
```

Plot the sequence using the resource function [MultipleAxesPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultipleAxesPlot):

```
options = {PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.0737601, 0.865914, 0.132145], 
     RGBColor[0.874018, 0.204385, 0.872946]}, 
   "SecondaryAxesColor" -> RGBColor[0.874018, 0.204385, 0.872946]};

ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesPlot"][Through[curves[x]], {x, 1, 20}, 
 Sequence @@ options]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice and creative (+1)! Happy New Year!

Comment: Thank you happy @Moo year (;

Comment: (+1) all suggestions were great, but the first one in particular was spectacular. happy new year!

Comment: Thank you @bmf (:. I thought the first might be liked more so I placed it first as an attention grabber (:. Happy new year !

Comment: Bonus that is not really related to  the question: Find a basis lower than 2023 where the digit representation of 2023 is palindromic : `Select[Table[{u, 2023 == IntegerReverse[2023, u]}, {u, 2, 
   2023}], #[[2]] &]` gives the following basis 16 : `{7, 14, 7}`; 118: `{17, 17}`; 288:`{7,7}` 2022 : `{1,1}`

Comment: @userrandrand: Love the languages addition!

Comment: @Moo Thanks (:. I figured it fits taking the title literally as "ways to write 2023" haha.

Comment: @Moo I recently realized that the number given in french is not how you pronounce the year in french.

Comment: I could have also tried translating word for word using `TextWords` and `WordTranslate` but that might have led to bad translations. There is also `TextTranslation` but it seems to require the cloud.

Comment: @Moo maybe Mathematica wrote the year in canadian french but I am not familiar with that french. It's strange that it uses the right form like "two thousand twenty three" in other mainly latin languages like spanish and portuguese but pronunces it as " twenty hundred twenty three" in french.

Comment: @userrandrand I am very impressed by the amount of work you did on your answer!!! A very small contribution, as a token of appreciation, if you wish to include it is the following: in Greek 2023 is δύο χιλιάδες είκοσι τρία.

Comment: @bmf Thank you it seems that "Greek" does not appear in the drop-down menu for `IntegerName` when entering a language but it still works when you type it. It also works with Greek given as an entity. Ευτυχισμένο το νέο έτος ! (Happy new year in Greek according to Google translate).

Comment: @userrandrand Google translate worked fine this time :)

Comment: @Moo I included the ASCII format in the table of ways to write 2023 in different languages as maybe it helps with pronunciation.

Comment: @bmf I realized I did not mention that I added Greek to the answer.

Comment: @userrandrand just saw it :-)

Answer (score 5):

According to the Goldbach conjecture, 2023 can be written as a sum of 3 primes... we can find these using:

```
FindInstance[2023 == a + b + c, {a, b, c} \[Element] Primes]
```

In fact, you can find lots of such 3-prime sums:

```
FindInstance[2023 == a + b + c, {a, b, c} \[Element] Primes, 10]
```

Can we find a so that $\lfloor (a-1/a)^2 \rfloor$ is equal to 2023? Sure thing:

```
$MaxPiecewiseCases = 3000; 
FindInstance[2023 == Floor[(a - 1/a)^2], a \[Element] Integers, 2]
```

And, inspired by the comment of E. Chan-López

```
FindInstance[2023 == (a + 1)^2 - a^2, a \[Element] Integers]
```