# Splitting a string into substrings of length 1 and 2

Tags: string-manipulation, partitions

There is already a thread on how to split a string into equal sized chunks.
I'm wanting to split a string into sets of substrings of length 1 and 2.
For example, if I have the string "123456", my list would include elements such as
{12,3,4,56},
{1,2,3,45,6},
and 
{1,2,34,56}.

I found [this little bit of Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457913/algorithm-to-partition-a-string-into-substrings-including-null-partitions), but 1) I don't know how to translate it into Mathematica code and 2) it gives you strings with a bunch of extra commas (because it's basically just distributing n commas through the string in different ways).

I suspect there is a very simple way of doing this in Mathematica.

Comment: Do your strings really all consist of digits? Are really string representations of integers?

Comment: Very closely related: [(5305)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5305)

Answer (score 6):

I am seeking a more elegant approach but this gets the job done:

```
stringChunk[str_String, ch : {_Integer?Positive ..}] :=
 Module[{dynP, n = StringLength@str},
  dynP[l_, p_] := MapThread[l ~StringTake~ {#, #2} &, {{0} ~Join~ Most@# + 1, #} &@Accumulate@p];
  dynP[str, #] & /@ Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, n, ch]
 ]
```

Test:

```
stringChunk["123456", {1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{"12", "34", "56"}, {"12", "34", "5", "6"}, {"12", "3", "45", "6"}, {"12", "3", "4", "56"},
>  {"1", "23", "45", "6"}, {"1", "23", "4", "56"}, {"1", "2", "34", "56"},
>  {"12", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, {"1", "23", "4", "5", "6"}, {"1", "2", "34", "5", "6"},
>  {"1", "2", "3", "45", "6"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "56"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}}
> ```

---

#### Explanation

Igor Rivin comments that my code is "difficult to parse" so here is an explanation:

- `dynP` is just a modified version of the function with the same name from [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7512#7512) operating on strings rather than lists.  It splits a string into the lengths given by its second parameter.
- `IntegerPartitions[n, n, ch]` gives a list of all splits of `n` into segments given by list `ch`, e.g.:

  ```
  IntegerPartitions[6, 6, {1, 2}]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
  > ```
- These are permuted, joined, and given to `dynP` to split the string `str` accordingly.

Comment: What is the complexity of this method?

Comment: @Igor Complexity over what variable?  String length?  I believe it is exponential, but so is the length of the result so I am not sure that can be avoided.  That is to say it is roughly constant time with regard to the length of the output list.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think Igor asked about the code complexity over the number of infixes. Ups! I did it again!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually, my comment about difficulty to parse was literal: you use all of Mathematica's syntactic feature, which leads to much more compact code, but is more difficult to read to those who are not used to it (like me). I did not mean it in a bad way at all, just as a statement of fact.

Answer (score 5):

I find it difficult to parse the runes in Mr.Wizard's answer, but here is a simple functional way:

```
substrs[str_] := substrs[str] = 
 If[StringLength[str] == 2, {Characters[str], {str}},  
  If[StringLength[str] == 1, {{str}},  
   Join[Map[Prepend[#, StringTake[str, 1]] &, substrs[StringDrop[str, 1]]],
    Map[Prepend[#, StringTake[str, 2]] &, substrs[StringDrop[str, 2]]]]]]
```

Here is the general version (where the chunks are of arbitrary bounded length. If you want to not bound the length, just call `allsubstrs[str, StringLength[str]]`

```
allsubstrs["", n_] := {{}}

prepsubstrs[oldlist_, prefix_] := Map[Prepend[#, prefix] &, oldlist]

allsubstrs[str_, n_] := 
  allsubstrs[str, n] = 
    Apply[Join,  
      Map[prepsubstrs[allsubstrs[StringDrop[str, #], n], 
         StringTake[str, #]] &, Range[Min[n, StringLength[str]]]]]
```

Comment: And I still haven't figured out how to typeset code properly :(

Comment: @Karsten7. I did look, but the four line feeds do not seem to work. I then looked at other people's postings, but they did not seem to do anything special either. Anyway, thanks! I am sure I will catch on eventually...

Comment: @Karsten7. Ah, so!

Comment: This appears to be an order of magnitude faster than my code.  (+1)  However as written it is not as general. (Mine will work with any given segment lengths.)  Will you consider posting a generalized version?  If not I may use your code as a basis for my own generalization.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I will certainly consider it, but am a little swamped at the moment, so it might take a little while, in the meanwhile, please feel free...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, I have added the more general version.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reasonably fast approach using the nice `SatisfiabilityInstances[]`:

```
ClearAll[stringSets];
stringSets[str_String] := Module[{x, len},
                          len = StringLength@str - 1;
                          StringSplit[StringJoin /@ (Riffle[Characters@str, #] & /@ 
                         (SatisfiabilityInstances[And @@ Table[Or[x[n], x[n + 1]], {n, 1, len - 1}], 
                                 Array[x, len], All] /. {True -> " ", False -> ""}))]
  ]

Timing[stringSets["12345678901234567890"];]
(* {1.078125, Null} *)

Length[stringSets["12345678901234567890"]]
(* 10946 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 stringbreak[str_] := (
        StringJoin[#[[All, 1]]] & /@
            GatherBy[Transpose[{Characters[str],
                 Accumulate@#}], #[[2]] & ] & /@
         Nest[ Flatten[ If[Last@# == 0, {Append[#, 1]},
              {Append[#, 0], Append[#, 1]}] & /@ # , 1] &, {{1}},# -1]) &@
                             StringLength[str]
  stringbreak["123456" ]
```

> {{"12", "34", "56"}, {"12", "34", "5", "6"}, {"12", "3", "45", 
>     "6"}, {"12", "3", "4", "56"}, {"12", "3", "4", "5", "6"}, {"1", 
>     "23", "45", "6"}, {"1", "23", "4", "56"}, {"1", "23", "4", "5", 
>     "6"}, {"1", "2", "34", "56"}, {"1", "2", "34", "5", "6"}, {"1", "2",
>      "3", "45", "6"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "56"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", 
>     "5", "6"}}

```
 stringbreak["12345678901234567890" ] // Timing // First
 stringbreak["12345678901234567890" ] // Length
```

> 0.546
>
> 10946

Extension to arbitraty max run length:

```
    stringbreak[str_, runlen_] :=
       StringJoin[#[[All, 1]]] & /@
            GatherBy[Transpose@{Characters@str, #}, Last ] & /@
               Nest[Flatten[ {Append[#, Last@# + 1],
                   If[Length@# > runlen - 1 && Length@Union@#[[-runlen ;;]] == 1 ,
                       Sequence @@ {}, Append[#, Last@#]]} & /@ #, 1] &, {{0}},
                           StringLength[str] - 1]  

    stringbreak["123456", 10]
```

> {{"123456"}, {"12345", "6"}, {"1234", "56"}, {"1234", "5", 
>     "6"}, {"123", "456"}, {"123", "45", "6"}, {"123", "4", 
>     "56"}, {"123", "4", "5", "6"}, {"12", "3456"}, {"12", "345", 
>     "6"}, {"12", "34", "56"}, {"12", "34", "5", "6"}, {"12", "3", 
>     "456"}, {"12", "3", "45", "6"}, {"12", "3", "4", "56"}, {"12", "3", 
>     "4", "5", "6"}, {"1", "23456"}, {"1", "2345", "6"}, {"1", "234", 
>     "56"}, {"1", "234", "5", "6"}, {"1", "23", "456"}, {"1", "23", "45",
>      "6"}, {"1", "23", "4", "56"}, {"1", "23", "4", "5", "6"}, {"1", 
>     "2", "3456"}, {"1", "2", "345", "6"}, {"1", "2", "34", "56"}, {"1", 
>     "2", "34", "5", "6"}, {"1", "2", "3", "456"}, {"1", "2", "3", "45", 
>     "6"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "56"}, {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}}

brute force just for fun..

```
 Function[str, Select[ Permutations[
        Join[ StringJoin /@ Partition[ # , 2, 1]  , #] &@Characters[str] ,
        StringLength[str]] , StringJoin@# == str & ]]@"123456"
```

> same, way slower.